# Pass variable through new <script> element

Tags: html, javascript

this function with

```
function setStorage() {
     localSorage.setItem("value", radio);
}
```

can only be executed and allow other functions to be executed if it is in a separate `<script>` element. now, that variable, radio, it needs to be written to storage but the browser said the variable if not defined, how do i get that variable without calling the function i unexpectedly?

if that makes sense...

Comment: You can either return the variable and use it after it is returned or set a global variable so everything can see it.

Comment: I think you'd get better help on Stack Exchange and/or Web Apps. It's there that you will get programming experts. I don't think this is the right place for programming.

Comment: Right, programming questions go on [so].

Comment: alright, I'll take that as advice.

Comment: If the variable isn't defined … then write a value to the variable first.